# What is "n" in the coroutine returned value?

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

I have the following coroutine and table that look like this:

```
co = coroutine.create(function(...)
  for item in pairs(table.pack(...)) do 
    coroutine.yield(item)
  end
  coroutine.yield('Evil')
  return 'NO!'
end)

values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

When I called resume, it yield the value as expected and suddenly yield `n` before `Evil`

```
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    1
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    2
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    3
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    4
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    5
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    6
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    n -- Here we have n
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    Evil
> coroutine.resume(co, table.unpack(values))
true    NO!
```

What does `n` stand for?

Comment: Side note: the `table.unpack(values)` in all your calls to `coroutine.resume` except the first don't do anything, because you don't do anything with the return value of `coroutine.yield`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Lua 5.2 (I guess), `table.pack()` works as `{...}`, but adds field 'n' that store number of items. That's the 'n' key you get.

Note that you're listing only keys, not the values itself.

If you don't want that 'n', use `ipairs()` instead of `pairs()`.